# importing UIKit or CoreGraphics?

Tags: ios, optimization, uikit, core-graphics

I've got a simple file that I want to keep low profile here. If I can lower build times I will. Between UIKit and CoreGraphics, which  is smaller / more compact and practical for my situation?

```
import CoreGraphics // can be replaced with import UIKit

let π = CGFloat(M_PI)
let twoπ = 2 * π
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CoreGraphics is the more compact one. UIKit itself relies on CoreGraphics. You don't need to import UIKit unless you need to use something defined in it.